# CSS Selected Item Navigation Arrow on Bottom

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am having trouble making a CSS styled navigation bar that has a white arrow (triangle) pointing upwards at the selected nav item.  The white arrow (triangle) blends with the body below, and is centered on the text box.  Something like this screenshot:

[image: example of what I'm trying to do]

Anyone have any suggestions on how to specify a "selected" CSS styling for the nav item as shown in the above screenshot?

I'm trying to create a CSS style called "activate", so `<li class="activate"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>` makes the arrow.  Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/v680tfvr/
which kind of works, but the highlighting is too big when the user hovers over the menu item, and a second little arrow appears near the top.  Seem simple, I just can't figure it out!

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle out of it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v680tfvr/ added the jsfiddle link to above too

Comment: Check if this works for you? https://jsfiddle.net/v680tfvr/2/

Comment: Thanks but there is still a mysterious little white arrow in the top middle.

Comment: I am checking it out buddy. Should be something with the `:after`.

Comment: Check now! It works now. Updated the answer.

Comment: lemme know if the answer is fine for you! `:)`

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/v680tfvr/5/. The final one! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the following changes:

- Fixed the Border
- Fixed the heading
- That mysterious thing doesn't appear on hover

#### Code

```
.submenu {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu .activate:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 75px;
    left: 40%;
    top: -39px;
    border-left: 10px outset transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
}
```

#### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v680tfvr/5/